# Will be returning to india with some gadgets, need to know on custom duty

Tags: air-travel, india, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens

I will be returning to india from UK. I will be bringing mobile phones and a laptop.

- 2 iPhone 5 (Used)
- 1 Samsung Galaxy S4 (new)
- 1 MacBook Pro 15" with retina display

will I have to pay custom duty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you will have to pay any custom duties because you can have at least one phone and a laptop along with other technology in your carry on when flying to various places. I haven't traveled specifically from the UK to India, but for other trips I've had my laptop a phone and cameras in my carry on and they didn't care at all, so I don't see why you wouldn't be able to bring multiple phones. The laptop is one of the most common things to bring in a carry on baggage however. You may or may not have to pay something for having multiple phones.

Here's a [source](http://www.indiabaggagerules.com/2008/01/laptop-rule.html) for at least one laptop computer.

Here's a [source](http://www.happyschoolsblog.com/cell-phones-usa-to-india-customs/) that refers to bring multiple devices from the US to India, I'm guessing it might be similar to UK to India.

I hope this helps! Safe travelling!